# Same customer block displaying 3 times

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.4

I am creating two new customer attributes in registration page, but it is displaying 3 places. this is my code

In **app/code/vendor/plugin/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  template="custom_module::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In **additionalinfocustomer.phtml**  i have display code for new attributes.

Note : it is working upto 2.1.13 and 2.2.3 but latest 2.2.4 i am getting above issue.

As per code it is calling following places

if you see default form/register.phtml following places it is calling

```
echo $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.extra') --line 19 
echo $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter') line 33 
echo $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info'); line 167.
```

but it should call only on 167

Comment: using plugin(interceptor) i have completed but still waiting for is there any possibility through layout file.

Comment: What is the issue, your custom attributes are displayed in Three places instead of one ? what are these three places ?

Comment: yes instead of one it is displaying three places, if you see default form/register.phtml  following placess it is calling 
echo $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.extra') --line 19
echo $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter') line 33
echo $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info'); line 167. but it should call only on 167

Answer (score 0):

Of course basically it should be displayed just in `form_additional_info` container, maybe you have some xml who contains the other blocks within that block.

Try to check the the xml files, or to work around this problem, you can use this:

**customer_account_create.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.info.customer"  template="custom_module::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**form/register.phtml**

```
<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('additional.info.customer');?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,but same code is working on magneto 2.0,2.1 up to 2.2.3 . why this issue only in 2.2.4. that is my question. i resolved issue by using interceptor concept. but still checking is there any possible way ?